# Flutter : Applying One Gradient For Full Background

Tags: flutter

How can i apply a gradient like [here](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/mono-bank-concept-app) to the app background? Can you see the gradient moving down on that the app bar and the scaffold body just like they were one widget and not 2 widgets that each has his own color?

Answer (score 19):

You need to use container as background to your scaffold to add a gradient. You can use [Opacity](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) widget as well to make container or any widget transparent. But here is the exact solution what you are looking for:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xFF282a57), Colors.black],
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 50, 20, 0),
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.white,),
                Spacer(),
                Text("Expense",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18,)),
                Spacer(),
                Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.white,)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Wrong, I actually found out on my own, you just gonna wrap the whole scaffold in a container and give it the gradient colors you want and then set the background of the scaffold and its elements to "Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0)" and it will work, i have tried it...

Comment: I have to say that the solution provided by Micheal is the way to go if you want the gradient also behind the appbar and bottomnavigation